# Laravel Echo - can't join presence channel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-echo

I'm trying to join a Presence channel using Javascript's library Echo. I can successfully join the regular channel.

So, this is what I did:

I fire the event like this:

```
 event(new FixtureChatroomEvent($userId, $message, $username, $profileImg, $fixtureId));
```

or like this

```
broadcast(new FixtureChatroomEvent($userId, $message, $username, $profileImg, $fixtureId))->toOthers();
```

The event looks like this (It looks ugly, I know, I will pass in a class later on):

```
class FixtureChatroomEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;
    public $username;
    public $profileImg;
    public $userId;
    public $fixtureId;

    public function __construct($userId, $message, $username, $profileImg, $fixtureId)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->profileImg = $profileImg;
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->fixtureId = $fixtureId;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('fixture-channel.' . $this->fixtureId);
    }
}
```

The listener method is simple, I only use handle method that looks like this:

```
public function handle(FixtureChatroomEvent $event)
{
    return $event;
}
```

It is also registered in `EventServiceProvider` like this :

```
    'App\Events\FixtureChatroomEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\FixtureChatroomEventListener'
    ],
```

channels.php (route) looks like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('fixture-channel.{fixtureId}', function ($user, $message, $username, $profileImg, $userId, $fixtureId) {
    return [
        'message' => $message, 
        'username' => $username, 
        'profileImg' => $profileImg, 
        'userId' => $userId, 
        'fixtureId' => $fixtureId
    ];
});
```

And `BroadcastServiceProvider` looks like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

Now the front end: I simply try to do something like this (I pass in the fixtures ID to the part of the channel name which is the same as the Events `fixtureId` - the channel name is correctly output):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fixtureChannel =`fixture-channel.${$('#fixture_id').text()}`;
    //var fixtureChannel = 'fixture-channel';
    console.log(fixtureChannel);
    Echo.join(fixtureChannel)
        .listen('FixtureChatroomEvent', (e) => {
            alert('ok');
            console.log('ok');
        })
        .here((users) => {
            console.log('123');
        })
        .joining((user) => {
            console.log(user.name);
        })
        .leaving((user) => {
            console.log(user.name);
        })    
    ;
});
```

Now the event is fired, but nothing is seen on the other side. I also tried joining the presence channel with no fixtureId, no success. No errors are shown. How can I even debug this?

The packages debugger (laravel-websockets) shows that the event was fired, but no connections are seen:

[image: This is when I get to the page (where the Echo code is supposedly called).]

[image: Event is callled]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);` line. I removed the middleware, like this: `Broadcast::routes();` I tried this before posting this question, but for the first time, the server returns a 500 error. Simply refreshing the page again helped.